# Manipulate value in Zend_Registry

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an array that I write into Zend_Registry:

```php
Zend_Registry::set('myArray', $myArray);
```

Now I want to add a new value to that array. I know that Zend_Registry is not a good choice at all and I know that it is kind of read-only. But is there any way to update it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is read-only?

Comment: @codezombie Kind of :) The answer below explains it better than I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been a long while since I have manipulated the registry as you have asked, however I think you can do the following:

```
$myArray = Zend_Registry::get('myArray');
$myArray['key'] = $value;
Zend_Registry::set('myArray',  $myArray);
```

This gets the value out of `Zend_Registry`, adds another element to the array, and sets it back into the registry again.